# Replace consecutive zeros found at either end of a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I need to replace any zeros within the first and last column of a dataframe with NA, but, when the first/last zero is replaced, I need to also replace any consecutive zeros present in that specific row. Given the example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                 b = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                 c = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                 d = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 e = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 f = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1))
df
```

I would need it to return:

```
df.result <- data.frame(a = c(1,NA,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1),
                        b = c(1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1),
                        c = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,NA,1,1,1),
                        d = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                        e = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                        f = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1))
df.result
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way, which avoids `apply` and operating on rows:

```
g<-lapply(df,"==",0)
df[do.call(cbind,Reduce("&",g,accumulate=TRUE)) | do.call(cbind,Reduce("&",g,accumulate=TRUE,right=TRUE))]<-NA
identical(df,df.result)
#[1] TRUE
```

A quick benchmark:

```
docendo<-function(df) {
  idx <- t(apply(df != 0, 1, function(x) cumsum(x) == 0 | rev(cumsum(rev(x)) == 0)))
  df[idx] <- NA
  df 
}

nicola<-function(df) {
  g<-lapply(df,"==",0)
  df[do.call(cbind,Reduce("&",g,accumulate=TRUE)) | do.call(cbind,Reduce("&",g,accumulate=TRUE,right=TRUE))]<-NA
  df
}

lmo<-function(df) {
   reps.first <- max.col(df, ties.method = "first") - 1
   reps.last <- max.col(df, ties.method = "last")
   fill.last <- length(df)-reps.last
   is.na(df[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(df))[reps.first > 0], reps.first[reps.first > 0]),
               sequence(reps.first))]) <- TRUE
   is.na(df[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(df))[fill.last > 0], fill.last[fill.last > 0]),
               length(df)-(sequence(fill.last) - 1))]) <- TRUE
   df
}
#create a bigger dataset
df<-df[rep(1:nrow(df),each=10000),]
system.time(res<-docendo(df))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  2.088   0.020   2.145
system.time(res2<-nicola(df))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.016   0.000   0.017
identical(res,res2)
#[1] TRUE
system.time(res3<-lmo(df))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.222   0.000   0.265
identical(res2,res3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! Although all options worked well, I marked this answer due to its speed.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following solution where we first build a logical matrix used for subsetting the data and assigning NA:

```
idx <- t(apply(df != 0, 1, function(x) cumsum(x) == 0 | rev(cumsum(rev(x)) == 0)))
df[idx] <- NA
```

The results are equal to your desired output:

```
all.equal(df, df.result)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In case you are worried about performance/memory, you could also do this in a two step approach where you first compute the rows in first and last column that are 0 and do the second step only on those rows.

```
idx1 <- rowSums(df[,c(1, ncol(df))] == 0)>0
idx2 <- t(apply(df[idx1,] != 0, 1, function(x) cumsum(x) == 0 | rev(cumsum(rev(x)) == 0)))
df[idx1,][idx2] <- NA
```

---

As a side note, you can also skip the intermediate step of creating an index if you use the following (though I prefer creating an index):

```
is.na(df) <- t(apply(df != 0, 1, function(x) cumsum(x) == 0 | rev(cumsum(rev(x)) == 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R method that uses `max.col` to identify the elements of each row to fill in and then uses matrix subsetting and `is.na<-` to fill in the NAs. The matrix is filled using `rep` and `sequence`.

```
# get the last of the 0 values from first column
reps.first <- max.col(df, ties.method = "first") - 1
# get the last of the 0 values starting with last column
reps.last <- max.col(df, ties.method = "last")
fill.last <- length(df)-reps.last

# fill in from first column
is.na(df[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(df))[reps.first > 0], reps.first[reps.first > 0]),
               sequence(reps.first))]) <- TRUE
# fill in from last column
is.na(df[cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(df))[fill.last > 0], fill.last[fill.last > 0]),
               length(df)-(sequence(fill.last) - 1))]) <- TRUE

all.equal(df, df.result)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I made an edit to my answer to include yours in the benchmark.